# Python 3: find item in list and answer based on that

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a python script that listens to Facebook chat using `fbchat` and searches  for the word `'cf'`. If that word is detected in chat, I want to send a pre-defined message `Answer1`. See below for my code and the error I get:

```py
from fbchat import log, Client
from fbchat.models import *

wordImLookingFor = ['cf']

Answer1 =['Hello! how can i help you']

# Subclass fbchat.Client and override required methods
class EchoBot(Client):
    def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
        self.markAsDelivered(thread_id, message_object.uid)
        self.markAsRead(thread_id)

        log.info("{} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type.name))

        # If you're not the author, echo
        if author_id != self.uid:
            if word in message_object:
                print("The word is in the list!")
                self.send(Message(text=answer1), thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)


             else:
                print("The word is not in the list!")



client = EchoBot('user', 'pass')


client.listen()
```

> Exception in parsing ...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
>   File "C:/Users/John/Downloads/fbd2.py", line 22, in onMessage
>       if word in message_object:
>   TypeError: argument of type 'Message' is not iterable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the API for [fbchat.models.Message](http://fbchat.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#fbchat.models.Message)

I believe you're looking for the text field

```
if word in message_object.text:
    print("The word is in the list!")
```

**EDIT:**

**Simple Solution**

For your next error, the `in` keyword is expecting a single string and not a list of strings. Since you're looking for several keywords in the message, execute that case statement for each word in the list.

```
if author_id != self.uid:
    for word in wordImLookingFor:
        if word in message_object.text:
            print("The word is in the list!")
            self.send(Message(text=answer1), thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
        else:
            print("The word is not in the list!")
```

**Scaled Solution**

Since you're going to eventually be searching for a set of multiple keywords, and presumably each keyword should elicit a different Answer, you can save some complexity by creating a dictionary of keyword:answer.

```
keywords = {'cf': 'Hello! how can i help you', 'key2': 'Answer2'}

class EchoBot(Client):
    def onMessage(self, author_id, message_object, thread_id, thread_type, **kwargs):
        self.markAsDelivered(thread_id, message_object.uid)
        self.markAsRead(thread_id)

        log.info("{} from {} in {}".format(message_object, thread_id, thread_type.name))

        if author_id != self.uid:
            for word in message_object.text.split():
                try:
                    self.send(Message(text=keywords[word]), thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=ThreadType.USER)
                    print(word + "is in the list!")
                except KeyError:
                    print(word + "is not in the list!")
```

Comment: Thank you : this is the new error i get after i added .text :TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: @GianiCurcubeu Check the definition `wordImLookingFor = ['ch']`, you initialize it as a list of strings instead of a single string

Comment: yes because 'wordImLookingFor = ['cf']' is just the first word, it will be a list of strings down the line as i will expand the list that it must look for, multiple triggers.

Comment: if you know a better way for me to make a variable containing multiple words to look for please enlighten me!

Comment: Thank you! your python skills are way far advanced then mine!   what i want to do i lead the conversation  he says " cf" i say "hello how are you" then if he stops respoding and next day answers to my "hello how are you".. "im fine. I need help" i want the to identify that and pick up from where is left and instead saying "hello how are you" it should say, "how can i help you today" and so on.

Comment: I will study and test and train on the code you gave me here can't thank you enough

Comment: Can i do a variable instead of 'cf ' : keywords = {'Variable': 'Hello! how can i help you', 'key2': 'Answer2'} where Variable is = ['hi','hello','howdy','good morning' and so on...] at it gives answer 1 Hello how can i help you?!

Comment: A variable can't be a key in a dictionary, but multiple keys can share the same value. `for word in ['hi', 'hello', 'howdy', 'good morning']: keywords[word] = 'Hello! How can I help you?'`

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is at self.send(Message(text=answer1)

It looks like you are trying to send text as a LIST instead of a string.

Message cannot iterate over the list, but wants a simple string.

```
Answer1 =['Hello! how can i help you']
Answer1 = 'Hello! How can I help you?'
```

Comment: Thank you i edited that i get the same error  : **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbchat\client.py", line 1542, in _parseMessage
    thread_id=thread_id, thread_type=thread_type, ts=ts, metadata=metadata, msg=m)
  File "C:/Users/John/Downloads/fbd2.py", line 25, in onMessage
    if word in message_object.text:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list**

Comment: Possibly the difference in **Answer1** vs **answer1**
Is there a reason Answer1 is not passed explicitly to the class?

Comment: If your answer is always 'Hello! How can I help you?' is there a reason you are defining it like this?   If you are going to have different words to look for and possibly different answers, you should set up a dictionary.  

    wordstolookfor = {'cf': 'Hello! How can I help you?', 'word2': 'response2'}

Comment: I will ,thank you, the answers i want to give are based on the answer received in chat, i try to lead the conversation to simple yes and no answers and based on that call an reposnse or the other. but as i am a simple python noob that is just learning. i'm starting with 1 chat first response